# If $f(x,y,z)$ takes a maximum $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ under $g(x,y,z)=1$ then $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla g$ at the point under any condition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One of my exam questions says

If $f(x,y,z)$ takes a maximum $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ under $g(x,y,z)=1$ then prove $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla g$ at the point.

Is it true general?

I think on surface it may never take max or min. When it is compact and $f$ is continuous, it takes. In this case, I need to separate interior and boundary. On the interior, the max will be local. Thus $\nabla f =0$ thus parallel. But on the boundary, I do not know of how to find out if they are parallel or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first order derivatives exist for $f$ and $g$, the [KKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions (a generalization of Lagrange multipliers) are necessary for a maximum. This precisely gives the condition that $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ in this case for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure what you're talking about compactness for as well - derivatives are defined on open sets which don't have boundaries.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, could you name me references for KKT and Lagrange multiplier methods? Since all the textbooks I have does not have sections on these topics, not even Lagrange one. Thanks. I'd prefer if the textbooks are rigorous in manner.

Comment: Bertsekas' Nonlinear Programming (Chapter 3) is reasonably rigorous, Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization (Chapter 5) is more casual. Theres also a short and much more casual discussion in Stewart's Calculus and presumably in other similar books.